# How to set chmod and permission to directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, devops

I have the `/var/log/journal` directory which I have deleted mistakenly.
I seen that in other server it has this permissions by default:

```
drwxr-sr-x+  3 root systemd-journal 4096 Oct 29 11:31 .
drwxrwxr-x  12 root syslog          4096 Oct 29 06:25 ..
drwxr-sr-x+  2 root systemd-journal 4096 Oct 29 13:26 0cdd6d5fe14532fe8a70632130e771b4
```

And after created this using root (in the server that it was deleted) it has this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Oct 29 14:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog 4096 Oct 29 14:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Oct 29 14:06 0cdd6d5fe14532fe8a70632130e771b4
```

How to make them even so it will have the same permissions as it was so background processes won't get blocked due to missing permissions or something else.

Comment: Why devoted the question?

Comment: The question doesn't look as a *programming* one, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign on `ls` output means there are some permissions set through an acl, you can check them using `getfacl` and set them accordingly with `setfacl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -R 755 0cdd6d5fe14532fe8a70632130e771b4
```

--> it will set the permissions like this drwxr-xr-x (rwx ==7 full access; r-x == 5 read and execute access) 
-R means apply it on the folder and subfolders

```
chown -R root:systemd-journal 0cdd6d5fe14532fe8a70632130e771b4
```

--> This will make the owner of the folder and subfolders the user root, and the group-owner systemd-journal.